# need to create xml that would be later parsed by perl

Tags: xml, parsing

I am creating XML that would be parsed by perl to do some task.

I am not able to go ahead and create xml  as it throws error. Below is XML that i created which perl complaints as erroneous.

```
<config>
 <dev>
   <dev_path="/home/chidori/dev/">
      <dev_logs_dir_under_path>
         <dev_script_log_path="/home/chidori/dev/script_log" retain_log="2" />
         <dev_db_log_path="/home/chidori/dev/db_log" retain_log="5" />
         <dev_cron_log_path="/home/chidori/dev/cron_log" retain_log="10" />
       </dev_logs_dir_under_path>  
  </dev>

 <prod>
   <prod_path="/home/chidori/prod/">
      <prod_logs_dir_under_path>
         <prod_script_log_path="/home/chidori/prod/script_log" retain_log="2" />
         <prod_db_log_path="/home/chidori/prod/db_log" retain_log="5" />
         <prod_cron_log_path="/home/chidori/prod/cron_log" retain_log="10" />
      </prod_logs_dir_under_path>   
 </prod>
</config>
```

Can someone please let me know what i have change in the XML so it works fine with perl. I am new to XML , so not sure what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you created doesn't meet the format of XML. XML requires all tags closed, and value should be assigned to attributes instead of element names.

Here's an example:

```
<config>
    <dev path="/home/chidori/dev/">
        <dev_logs_dir_under_path>
            <dev_script_log path="/home/chidori/dev/script_log" retain_log="2" />
            <dev_db_log path="/home/chidori/dev/db_log" retain_log="5" />
            <dev_cron_log path="/home/chidori/dev/cron_log" retain_log="10" />
        </dev_logs_dir_under_path>  
    </dev>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks , it works now :) , is there any good books/online materials that you refer to know more about XML ?